# Will PDO's LastInsertID Break AWS Replication?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo, database-replication, last-insert-id

Does the PDO `lastinsertid` function use MySQL's `last_insert_id` function?

I'm particularly interested in replication with `AWS` and per the AWS [manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_MySQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html) using some MySQL functions break replication:

> Other common situations that can cause replication errors include the following:...Using unsafe nondeterministic queries

The `mysql` [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html) states that the functions I'm using aren't actually unsafe though:

> Nondeterministic functions not considered unsafe

I plan to rewrite my `now()` usages but am not sure how I can avoid the `last_insert_id` since PDO, not I, am querying that. I can't do a separate `select` because it is likely an `insert` was run in parallel and I'll get back the wrong id.

Comment: Regarding how the PDO function is implemented, [the source is here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L286). It uses an internal function of the MySQL driver, `mysql_insert_id`, which [reads a value already fetched during execution](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4f1d7cf5fcb11a3f84cff27e37100d7295e7d5ca/libmysql/libmysql.cc#L881). So no extra call to MySQL is triggered, but I've no idea what the implications for replication are.

Comment: If you use `binlog_format=ROW` or even `MIXED`, then you won't have to worry about non-deterministic queries. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-formats.html

Comment: `NOW()` is safe even when you use statement-based replication. See the list of "not unsafe" (sic) functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html

Comment: @BillKarwin I have `binlog_format=ROW, mixed` in the AWS instance. That broke the replication there. I have not had this issue when using standard mysql instances, I've used `mixed` in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, the various bindings (like PDO's) and the underlying functionality **are deterministic.** You can use them with confidence.

For example this is deterministic and will work everywhere.

```
  INSERT INTO master (address, town) VALUES('150 Broadway', 'New York');
  INSERT INTO detail (master_id, item) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'pepperoni pizza');
```

This is not. This is the sort of thing you're warned against.

```
  INSERT INTO master (address, town) VALUES('150 Broadway', 'New York');
  SELECT @id := MAX(master_id) FROM master;   /* bad bad bad */
  INSERT INTO detail (master_id, item) VALUES (@id + 1 'pepperoni pizza');
```